# DialogFragment and Activity Dialog. Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-dialog

I'm displaying a Dialog activity and a DialogFragment in Android. The fragment is below activity ( an activity overlaps the fragment. The activity is background). How can I make that the fragment will be foreground?

Comment: please provide screen shot or code.Those will be helpful to understand the problem more clearly

Answer (score 0):

As far I understand situation you described, you have something like that:

- Activity with attached DialogFragment
- Dialog Activity displayed from above activity/fragment

If that's correct answer to your question is "call `onBackStack()` in  Dialog Activity", which will cause terminating Dialog Activity and resume DialogFragment (along with its activity or to be more precise - resume activity and DialogFragment that it does have in FragmentManager stack).

I hope this answer will help you.

Comment: But I don't want to terminate Dialog Activity. I would like my DialogFragment was foreground and

Comment: I'm afraid there's no way to move DialogFragment from (below of DialogActivity) to be above. You can try with workaround (ugly one) like persisting DialogFragment data (`bundle`) and open new instance with that data. But I would consider redesign.